# Updated to EF5 now NotMapped annotation doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I just updated the entityframework to the latest 5.0.0 version. And the `NotMapped` annotation doesn't work now. I tried to google for an answer to fix it but couldn't find. Anyone had the same problem when you updated the entityframework and know a solution to fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there any exception or does EF ignore your annotation?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka it says that `the type or namespace 'NotMapped' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference)` I just did a package-update on the console. So the assembly still should be reference.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Annotation attributes in EF 5.0 with .NET 4.5 were moved to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

[**NotMapped**] is in **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema**. Make sure to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` to your code.