# Passing ICloneable Class throws Proxy error

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, icloneable

I have a `PhoneRecord` that is passed to an `EditWindow` so that a user is able to edit the record. On each `PhoneRecord` there is a type of `CostCode`. On the `EditWindow` I clone a record to break the reference to the `SelectedRecord` so that in case the user clicks on cancel I can pass back an unmodified version of the `PhoneRecord`. Here is how I clone:

```
public ModifyPhoneRecordViewModel(PhoneRecord passedRecord)
{
    SelectedRecord = passedRecord;
    _tempRecord = passedRecord.Clone() as PhoneRecord;
}
```

The `PhoneRecord` is a partial class generated by EF so here is how I implement `ICloneable`

```
partial class PhoneRecord : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return (PhoneRecord)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on cancel I pass back the `_tempRecord` and do some processing with it to revert to it's original state in the `DataGrid`/`TextBoxes`:

```
private void ProcessCancelCommand(PhoneRecord passedRecord)
{
    DataGridRecords[DataGridRecords.IndexOf(DataGridRecords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == passedRecord.Id))] = passedRecord;

    SelectedRecord = passedRecord;

    Application.Current.MainWindow.Activate();
}
```

However, this throws an error and the `CostCode` is wiped from the `TextBox`:

> "The entity wrapper stored in the proxy does not reference the same
>   proxy"

Is there a way in which I can prevent this so I can pass back a `PhoneRecord` with a valid `CostCode` on it?

Comment: You are trying to copy DB entity, that uses lazy loading and therefore it's just a proxy. That's why code throwing an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770369/get-underlying-entity-object-from-entity-framework-proxy Provides an unproxy method

Comment: @DanilEroshenko So do I need to use something like `var x = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(_tempRecord.GetType());` ? How does that return a useable `PhoneModel` to me?

Comment: I was pointing at UnProxy method actually. Also I think that Clone using serialization should also work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try not to use the `MemberwiseClone()` method to clone your entity:

[EntityFramework - Entity proxy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315233/entityframework-entity-proxy-error)

...but simply create a new entity class yourself:

```
partial class PhoneRecord : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new PhoneRecord()
        {
            CostCode = this.CostCode,
            //+ all other properties...
        }
    }
}
```

You don't want to clone the proxy class.

Comment: let's say you have 100+ properties. this makes your head explode.