# Entity Framework model first how to exclude certain table from generating sql script

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 model first approach. Is there any simple approach to exclude table from generating sql script or t-4 template is the only way?

The issue in my case is that I'm using view in SQL Server side and have a table with the same name in DataContext. Therefore  I do not need to create sql script for this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark any properties that do not map to the database with the NotMapped annotation.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx

OR

[Updated to EF5 now NotMapped annotation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194267/updated-to-ef5-now-notmapped-annotation-doesnt-work)

And

[Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)

Comment: Thank you for reply. As I wrote in the topic there is a conflict with table name in model and view name in database. I need somehow avoid creating whole table, not a distinct fields. I use model first approach, and it seems to me the only way for this is to use T-4 templates.